# jQuery POST not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I have written a script that fires a jQuery POST to retrieve data from a server side file as JSON, the code is below:

```
$.post("myfile.php", function(authDataset) {
    alert(authDataset);
});
```

A sample of what would be returned is:

```
{"firstName":"x","lastName":"y","boximg":"z"}
```

The handler file is working perfectly, when provided with the data the function all works fine, hoever the jquery POST function just isn't working. I've also tried GET and AJAX.

**It is placed within the document.ready tag**, I have ran every error checker including jsLint and jsFiddle but for some reason it's not firing at all.

I've used alerts inside and outside the post function, but the post() isn't getting called.

Can anyone offer a suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Your callback function only fires if the ajax request is successful (status 200).  You need to use a tool like firebug or chrome web inspector to see what your myfile.php is returning.  Also you could specify a `error` callback if you use `$.ajax`.

Comment: I've run firebug and IE error console, there are no errors. I'll switch back to AJAX and add the error callback, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Look in the `net` tab subtab `xhr`.  Look and see if there is a request to your php file and post the header.  There won't be a JS error, the error will likely be on the server side.

Comment: I'll take a look now, however I have newrelic monitoring the PHP server and its not reported any errors or warnings.

Comment: It might not be a php error, it could be a 400,401,401 etc. which might register with the tool you spoke of.

Comment: unfortunately not, its returning status 200 with 100% up time. This is why I can't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Try specifying the `"json"` as an argument after the success callback and verify that the responce header "Content-type" is also JSON.  And put a `console.log` before your `alert`.

Comment: The console.log stated the origin policy error, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A HTACCESS file on the server was forcing an SSL, which violates the Same origin policy.